# Javascript execute function depending on two buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need something like an if/else function that is executed depending on the combination of buttons.

I know it has to be like:

```
if "button1" is active/clicked {
  if "button2" is clicked{
    do sth.}
  else if "button3" is clicked{
    do sth. else}
}
```

The function should be executed when the second button is clicked. 
I can't find a reference for that

Comment: Please write your html and also write what have you tried.

Comment: By "buttons" you mean keyboard keys?

Comment: show some code to understand your problem better....

Comment: I'm not sure why this question has been voted down. It's a new user and a legitimate question. It's clearly stated that they want to react to clicks and it's tagged properly. What they mean by *button* is clearly defined by the Javascript context. I guess there are just some mean people here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to identify if a button has been clicked ...

```js
var button1 = false;
var button2 = false;

var button_action = function(btn) {
  var msg = document.getElementById('button_message');
  if (btn.value == 'button1') {
    button1 = true;
  } else if (btn.value == 'button2') {
    button2 = true;
  }
  if (button1 && button2) {
    msg.innerHTML = 'Both buttons have been clicked';
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="buttons" id="buttons">
  <input type="button" value="button1" onclick="button_action(this);">
  <input type="button" value="button2" onclick="button_action(this);">
</form>

<h1 id="button_message">No buttons have been clicked</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that, do the following:

1. create a variable telling which button is clicked
2. add `click` event to your buttons
3. add your conditions

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/npna5a3z/)

---

### Snippet:

```js
function addEvent(el, name, func, bool) {
 if (el.addEventListener)
  el.addEventListener(name, func, bool);
 else if (el.attachEvent)
  el.attachEvent('on' + name, func);
 else
  el['on' + name] = func;
}
var clicked = {
 button1: false,
 button2: false,
 button3: false
};

function eventFunc(e) {
 var t = e.target;
 if (t.hasAttribute('id') && clicked.hasOwnProperty(t.id))
  clicked[t.id] = true;
 
 if (clicked['button1']) {
  if (clicked['button2'])
   alert('button1 and button2 clicked!');
  else if (clicked['button3'])
   alert('button1 and button3 clicked!');
 }
}

addEvent(button1, 'click', eventFunc, false);
addEvent(button2, 'click', eventFunc, false);
addEvent(button3, 'click', eventFunc, false);
```

```html
<input type="button" value="button1" id="button1">
<input type="button" value="button2" id="button2">
<input type="button" value="button3" id="button3">
```

Hope that helped :)